# Newly Resized Luns not Showing correct LUN Size RHel 5.3

Tags: linux

My linux servers are not showing their newly resized fibre  Luns after being extended on the fly(online).the storage guys have  successfully resized the LUNS from 1Tb to 2 Tb .We are running fibre SAN ((on HP EVA kit,PSV450) not ISCSI LUNS on RHEL 5.3 Linux machines.
I have done the following below but unsuccessful, I  still cannot see the new size of 2Tb , i still see the old size of 1Tb.Please note that these LUNS are configured as raw devices for oracle and hence no LVMs are used .

Have i missed any procedure

Rescan  scsi bus
1. echo 1 > /sys/block/sda/device/rescan
   echo 1 > /sys/block/sdb/device/rescan

Update Size of your multipath device

multipathd -k"resize map orac_backup"

3.resize2fs /dev/mapper/orac_backup
(seems to fail probably a procedure not needed  in this scenario)

I alo tried this to  test multipath failover by running]
multipathd -k
del path sda 
add path sda

del path sdb 
add path sdb

All commands run successfuly but still old LUN size is showing, the Linux OS or kernel  still doesnt see the new Lun size.I have tried several times and  also restarted multipath service in between each  procedure numbered(listed) above, but still unsuccessful.Please help, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards
D

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/66638/how-to-extend-a-san-based-vdisk-in-red-hat-without-rebooting/97096#97096

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to flush and reload the maps after the rescan? 
multipath -f orac_backup and after that multipath -r

- L